# Test not defined in XML error while executing MFTF custom test

Tags: magento-2.3

I am trying to create a custom test case in MFTF 2.3.14 and Magento 2.3.1 . I am using `StorefrontPersistedCustomerLoginTest.xml` as a template and trying the custom test `StorefrontLoginRequiredFieldTest.xml` by just sending empty string for email and password field and validating the error messages. When I try running the test, I am getting below error.

```
In TestObjectHandler.php line 81:

  Test StorefrontLoginRequiredFieldTest not defined in xml.
```

I have created the custom test under

```
/var/www/html//var/www/html/magtiretest/app/code/ISNEZTire/login- 
  module/Test/Mftf.
```

1. I tried existing working test case 
   `StorefrontPersistedCustomerLoginTest.xml` and just changed the name of the 
   test (the content except test name) are same as existing one) and ran. 
   With new name, even the existing test cases are not working.
2. Instead of keeping the custom test in the new folder 
   `/var/www/html//var/www/html/magtiretest/app/code/ISNEZTire/login- 
   module/Test/Mftf`, I kept it in the folder where the existing working test is.

Still getting:

```
In TestObjectHandler.php line 81:

   Test StorefrontLoginRequiredFieldTest not defined in xml.
```

.env file

```
MAGENTO_BASE_URL=http://99.33.111.248/magtiretest/
MAGENTO_BACKEND_NAME=admin
MAGENTO_ADMIN_USERNAME=admin
MAGENTO_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin@123
BROWSER=chrome
//TESTS_BP=~/magtiretest/dev/tests/acceptance/tests/functional
//FW_BP=~/magtiretest/vendor/magento/magento2-functional-testing- 
framework
//FW_BP=~/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework
//MODULE_WHITELIST=Magento_Framework,Magento_ConfigurableProductWishlist,
  Magento_ConfigurableProductCatalogSearch,Magento_login-module
  MODULE_WHITELIST=Magento_login-module,Magento_Framework
  CUSTOM_MODULE_PATHS=/var/www/html/magtiretest/app/code/ISNEZTire/login- 
  module
  SELENIUM_HOST=SELENIUM_HOST=127.0.0.1
  SELENIUM_PORT=4444
  SELENIUM_PROTOCOL=http
  SELENIUM_PATH=/wd/hub
```

I tried all the configuration that are commented too

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
vendor/bin/mftf run:test StorefrontLoginRequiredFieldTest --remove --force
```